# error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

Tags: c++, types, structure

```
10  struct element
11  {
12      int listnum;
13      char *tablename;
14      char** headl;
15      float** tabledata;
16      struct element *next;
17  };
18
19  struct element *next = NULL;
20  struct element *start= NULL;
21
22  void add_element(char *tablenameadd, char **headladd, float **tableadd, int hcols, int trows, int tcols)
23  {
24      int a=1;
25
26      struct element *pointer;
27
28  element.headl = new char*[hcols];
29  element.tabledata = new float*[trows][tcols];
...
```

I get an error while debugging this in eclipse as a C++ project. The 2 error-codes I receive are both

> expected unqualified-id before '.' token

for program lines 28 and 29

Is there anyone able to help?

I changed it from a C project to a C++ project yesterday.

Comment: Don't post the line numbers. Just post the code instead and try to format your question.

Comment: There is no such variable as element. There is a struct called element pointed to by pointer but you aren't accessing it.

Comment: `element.headl` should be `pointer->headl`

Comment: You need to initialize `pointer` , and assign to it, and not to the `element` type.

Comment: Also since you use the heap element should probably not be a struct but a class with 'the rule of 3' fulfilled.

Comment: thing is i need it not constantalso changed the '.' to '::' and received lot of error codes more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the statement

```
element.headl
```

is wrong because element is the name of the data type, and what you are trying to do in to manipulate the structure defined under the name **pointer** so you have to change that to:

```
struct element *pointer;
pointer->headl = new char*...
```

Answer (score 0):

`element` here is a struct that you have declared and so you cannot do this

```
element.headl = new char*[hcols];

element.tabledata = new float*[trows][tcols]
```

You can do this-

```
void add_element(
    char *tablenameadd, char **headladd, float **tableadd,
    int hcols, int trows, int tcols)
{
  struct element *pointer;
  int a = 1;

  pointer = new element;

  pointer->headl = new char *[hcols];
  pointer->tabledata = new float *[tcols * trows];
}
```